# Getting the drive's items from Microsoft Graph API: The request is malformed or incorrect

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am trying to get a drive's items via the Microsoft Graph Api (SDK) and tried the following options:

1. `_graphServiceClient.Drives[driveInfo.Id].Items.Request().GetAsync()`:, this unfortunately results in an error with message error with message **"The request is malformed or incorrect"** and code **"invalidRequest"**. If I execute `_graphServiceClient.Drives[driveInfo.Id].Request().GetAsync()` however, I get back all drives but the `Items` property is `null`.
2. `_graphServiceClient.Drives[driveInfo.Id].Request().Expand(d => d.Items).GetAsync()`, this also results in an error with message **"The request is malformed or incorrect"** and code **"invalidRequest"**.

I don't know how to go on from here, still researching, but the documentation is leaving me clueless at the moment. Anyone success with either `.Expand()` or getting the actual files from a Drive?

Thanks,
Y

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You only use `Items` when you're fetching a single `DriveItem`:

```
await graphClient
  .Me
  .Drive
  .Items[item.Id] 
  .Request()
  .GetAsync();

await graphClient
  .Drives[drive.Id]
  .Items[item.Id]
  .Request()
  .GetAsync();
```

When you want to retrieve a `DriveItem` collection, you need to specify the root folder:

```
await graphClient
  .Me
  .Drive
  .Root // <-- this is the root of the drive itself
  .Children // <-- this is the DriveItem collection
  .Request()
  .GetAsync();

await graphClient
  .Drives[drive.Id]
  .Root 
  .Children
  .Request()
  .GetAsync();
```

The SDK unit tests are a good source for quick examples. For example, [`OneDriveTests.cs`](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/tests/Microsoft.Graph.DotnetCore.Test/Requests/Functional/OneDriveTests.cs) contains several examples for addressing Drives and DriveItems.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this clarifies a lot! Got it working, excellent!

Comment: The OneDriveTests.cs file seems to have moved to here now: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/tests/Microsoft.Graph.DotnetCore.Test/Requests/Functional/OneDriveTests.cs (the link at the bottom of the answer 404s). However, your answer has enabled me to finally retrieve a drive item - so thank you very much!